# Schedule Scrapy Spider via Batch with Win10 Task-Scheduler

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduled-tasks

I´m still pretty new to python, but I managed to get my spider to crawl the things I need.

Then I created a batch file, to run that spider. The batch looks like this:

```
call C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat
call cd cmc\cmc\spiders\
call scrapy runspider cmc_job.py -o out3.csv
```

> Line1 switches the cmd to python
>
> Line2 goes to the corresponding path
>
> Line3 runs the spider, which saves the data to an csv file.

This works fine, as long as I click the batch (mouse or keyboard) - but when scheduled with Win10 Task Scheduler, it does not work... The cmd windows opens for 1/2 sec, I think it does not wait for the first line to be executed, so line 3 is a bad command and then it closes.

Once again, it works fine when started manually, so I don´t get the difference between executing by hand and by system.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following syntax, it works for me in Windows task scheduler. Notice the quotes and the invokation of cmdline.py

```
@Echo Off
REM activate Python venv
CALL "C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat"
CD "C:\cmc\cmc\spiders\"
CALL "C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Tribic\Anaconda2\Scripts\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py" runspider cmc_job.py -o out3.csv
deactivate
```

Comment: Sir! Thank you very much - this works fine. I only had to remove both \Script\ in the paths for python.exe and cmdline.py; thanks again! now open the gates - data is coming :)